# SASS grid repeat go outsite of screen

Tags: html, css, sass

I use a display grid in my SASS files and in some element divs go outside of the screen and I have to scroll to the right to see all of the divs, can you advice what do I do wrong? This is my SASS.

When I change the repeat number to 5 everything works properly but break the line

```
.addresses
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr)
    justify-items: center

@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
    .addresses
        grid-template-columns: 1fr
        padding-bottom: 1rem
```

and this is address

```
<div class="addresses" formGroupName="address">
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="type">
          <mat-label>Typ</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="number">
          <mat-label>SN</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="apartNumber">
          <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="street">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="city">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="postCode">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relay">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relayType">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
       <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relayNumber">
          <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Without it, we have no idea what your SASS is doing.

Comment: @disinfor added html

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with your SASS. It's the `input` element base width that's causing it. If you inspect your `input`, you can see the dimensions are set to about 145px wide.

To fix this, set the `input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }` This will make the input take up the grid space that it is allotted and set the padding, outline and border to be included in the 100%.

```css
.addresses {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .addresses {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="addresses" formGroupName="address">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="type">
      <mat-label>Typ</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="number">
      <mat-label>SN</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="apartNumber">
      <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="street">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="city">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="postCode">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relay">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relayType">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput style="color:blue" formControlName="relayNumber">
      <mat-label>Hasło</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, there's something else in your code. It works in the snippet provided.